# Pass by const ref in function

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

If eventually we want the object to own another object, what's the use of passing by const reference.

Ex.

```
class OrderBook
{
    set<Order> orders;
    void insert_Bid(const Order &order);

}

void OrderBook::insert_Bid(const Order &order)
{
    orders.insert(order);
}
```

When we are inserting the order into the orders set, it is anyways going to copy over the `const Order &order`

Is the above code any better than:

```
class OrderBook
{
    set<Order> orders;
    void insert_Bid(Order order);

}

void OrderBook::insert_Bid(Order order)
{
    orders.insert(order);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: passing by const ref is efficient. No new object is constructed by the call.

Comment: If your version without const ref would use `std::move`, it would be more efficient. As it is, it's additional copy (unless compiler optimizes it, not sure this case would fall under guaranteed copy ellision).

Comment: You don't save the copy from `order` to `orders` at the insert, but you save the copy to from the caller to `insert_Bid(<order_argument>)` to the `order` parameter.

Comment: If you don't need the object at the place where you're inserting, you could also use an rvalue reference parameter `(Order&& order)`. That way you might be able to avoid the copy altogether.

Comment: If your version without const ref used `std::move` when inserting into the set, it *could* be more efficient, but only if the argument to `insert_Bid` were itself populated with move-semantics. Otherwise it still has one unavoidable copy. As-written, the first is more efficient because there is no copy from the caller to `insert_Bid`, and one copy within `insert_Bid` when inserting into `orders`; the second has two copies: one from the caller to `order` in `insert_Bid`, and another from `order` to `orders`.

Comment: passing by `const&` for efficiency is outdated. As pointed out by @Yksisarvinen, the modern semantic is to pass by value and move into place. The worst case scenario for it is 1 copy. The best case is no copies. For passing by `const&`, the worst case is 1 copy, but the best case is also 1 copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't save the copy from `order` to `orders` at the insert, but you save the copy to from the caller to `insert_Bid(<order_argument>)` to the order parameter